# std::memset with zero count and invalid pointer

Tags: c++

Is it safe to call `std::memset(pointer, ch, count)` with invalid pointer (e.g., `nullptr` or junk) when `count` equals 0?

Comment: It does fall under the as-if rule (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). So it seems to be safe to do so. But I can't find explicit confirmation in the standard

Comment: [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) says UB, [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) doesn't so I'm not sure

Comment: I believe the ISO C++ standard refers to the ISO C standard regarding the functions from the C standard library. Therefore, it may be more appropriate to make this a C question than a C++ question, unless a specific C++ rule is relevant here.

Comment: No, and this has been covered multiple times at Cppcon (don't have the bandwidth right now, but I think https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7entxbQOCc will cover it).  You're not allowed to pass NULL as either the source or destination, and compilers are free to optimize accordingly.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243012/is-it-guaranteed-to-be-safe-to-perform-memcpy0-0-0

Comment: Clang does gives a warning about size 0, MSVC/gcc do not : https://godbolt.org/z/3TzKfGT16.

Comment: Based on the comments, the TL;DR is: **No**, it is _not_ safe to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8597034/1918193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that causes undefined behavior. For example:

```
void* p = get_address(); // may return null
size_t sz = get_size();  // zero if previous returned null

memset(p, 0, sz); // Compiler may assume that p is not null

if (p) { // this null-check can be omitted since we "know" p is not null
  foo(p);
}
```

And indeed, if you look at the [code generated by GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aqGMx3Kbo):

```
main:
        push    rbx
        call    get_address()
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    get_size()
        mov     rdi, rbx
        xor     esi, esi
        mov     rdx, rax
        call    memset
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    foo(void*) ; <-- unconditional call
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

You can see that the "if" branch is omitted.